# Проблема с realm-java

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Использую библиотеку *Realm.io* для передачи данных в график *MPAndroidChart*. Добавляю в базу так:

```
protected void writeToDB() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    realm.beginTransaction();

    float f = 24;
    int i = 5;
    String s ="1100";;

    RealmDemoData d = new RealmDemoData(f, i, s);
    realm.copyToRealm(d);

    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Все добавляется, все хорошо, пытаюсь получить данные:

```
RealmResults<RealmDemoData> result = mRealm.allObjects(RealmDemoData.class);

RealmLineDataSet<RealmDemoData> set = new RealmLineDataSet<RealmDemoData>(result, "value", "xIndex");
```

И сразу вылетают ошибки, причем только когда использую `RealmLineDataSet`.
Сама ошибка:

```
02-06 23:21:13.676 6597-6597/com.akefa.smarthome002 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.realm.RealmResults.sort
                                                                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet.<init>(RealmBaseDataSet.java:71)
                                                                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet.<init>(RealmBarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet.java:32)
                                                                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineScatterCandleRadarDataSet.<init>(RealmLineScatterCandleRadarDataSet.java:39)
                                                                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet.<init>(RealmLineRadarDataSet.java:43)
                                                                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineDataSet.<init>(RealmLineDataSet.java:95)
                                                                      at com.akefa.smarthome002.weather.MultiLineChartActivity.setData(MultiLineChartActivity.java:52)
                                                                      at com.akefa.smarthome002.weather.MultiLineChartActivity.onResume(MultiLineChartActivity.java:45)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2109)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ваш класс `RealmDemoData` наследник `RealmObject` и класс `RealmLineDataSet` существует? Вы получаете ошибку, что класс или метод, который вы пытаетесь вызвать не существует.

Answer (score 2):

Да все верно, ошибка была в RealmLineDataSet классе, в подключаемом jar не верно было указано размещение RealmDinamicObject, подключил как модуль и проблема решилась, спасибо!